# How to prevent particular program from using particular network connection under Windows?

Tags: windows, group-policy, network-monitoring, bandwidth-control, 3g

In my company almost every user has 3G mobile connection and many of them travel a lot.

To prevent expensive mobile charges **I'm looking for a solution that would prevent particular program (Windows Updates, Dropbox, etc.) from using 3G/Mobile Broadband connection.**

Ideally connection rules should be controlled globally (GPO, global admin portal or similar)

Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: When doing research I've found post that may be helpful, it refers to Windows Updates and Windows Firewall but may be not use for us as we use check point one build into VPN client.

http://superuser.com/questions/135408/disable-windows-update-when-on-3g-network

Answer (score 0):

as and easy and dirty way could be to set up a local DNS server/forwarder with the dropbox, windows update, etc stuff set to localhost that they cannot access the internet at all. problem with that is for sure, that you cannot administrate it from remote.

if all internet connections go through the firewall, you could maybe introduce some specific forwarding rules depending on where the connections is coming from. extra dhcp range for all 3g connections if they're coming in on a different interface.

I don't think thats a solution, but somehow i couldn't add it as a comment.